# Problems Installing Pacemaker in AWS Amazon Linux

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, pacemaker, amazon-linux

I am trying to install Pacemaker in my Amazon Linux and I couldn't find it in the repo anymore following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@gt.anand1994/ha-cluster-with-elasticip-using-corosync-and-pacemaker-a013d288ae8) with sudo yum install pacemaker.

i then further search and found [this](https://www.allcloud.io/how-to/how-to-install-pacemaker-in-amazon-ami/), and to no avail the [repo link](https://clusterlabs.org/rpm-next/rhel-6/clusterlabs.repo) provided in the tutorial does not exist anymore.

my 3rd  attempt was to download the package from [git](https://github.com/ClusterLabs/pacemaker.git) and package it myself, but i've been faceing alot of dependency issues. and im currently stuck at needing a libcmap when running ./configure

any suggestion to get this installed?
im really stuck here.

Comment: Use a Linux distribution that provides pacemaker.

Comment: I can only use Amazon Linux in this case. any workaround to this? based on other resources, it seems that amazon used to include it in their repos, perhaps they removed it?

Comment: I've never heard of Amazon Linux including pacemaker. Of course, Amazon Linux is almost always the wrong choice of distribution. You should try very hard to solve whatever problem prevents you from using something else.

Comment: Amazon Linux does make it difficult to install software easily. I think your best bet is to build from source and keep at it until you have the dependencies all worked out. Document things as you go, then post here or elsewhere a good tutorial for the next person who wants use it :) I use Amazon Linux but if I have to rebuild my personal server it'll likely be with Ubuntu.